# How to find size of list/tuple in python in constant time

Tags: python, pointers

I am a novice in Python. I was just wondering if one can find the length of list or tuple in O(1) time. *(len() is O(n))*

In C, I can achieve similar thing as follows:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4 ,5};
printf("Length of Array a is :: %d\n", sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
```

I know that the above concept works on addresses and that is why it is possible in C, while as per my understanding, Python does not deal in addresses. However I still wanted to ask this question for the sake of curiosity.

Comment: you can do `sys.getsizeof(my_list)/sys.getsizeof(my_list[0])` however this wont work in cases like `my_list=[1,2,"apple",12.3,[1,2,3]]` for obvious reasons

Comment: Did you actually read somewhere that `len()` is O(n)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `len()` on a list in Python is `O(1)`. See [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you think it'd be O(n)?

Comment: oh wow. I would say it was just a random thought the list would be traversed first to get the length.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this works in O(1) in C is not because it deals in "addresses" but rather because the size is known at compilation time. In fact if you were to use sizeof() on a dynamically allocated array you would always get the size of a pointer.

In python though you want to use len().